# Proving combinator identity KMN=M

Tags: lambda-calculus

Have a problem proving **K** MN=M

1. By the **K** combinator definition

   $ (\lambda x y.x) M N $
2. Parenthesized

   $ ((\lambda x. (\lambda y.x)) M) N $
3. By the principal axiom of lambda calculus

   $ (\lambda y.M) N $
4. Second application of the principal axiom

   $ M[y:= N] $ ?

This would give correct result if M is y-free. Apparently there is an error at one of the steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reduce $(\lambda x.\lambda y.x)M$, the result is $(\lambda y.x)[x:= M]$. This substitution is only defined if$y$ is not free in $M$. Otherwise the $\lambda y$ will need to be $\alpha$-renamed before you can proceed.

Some texts define the substitution function to do this $\alpha$-renaming implicitly, others consider the result of the substitution to be undefined if the variable capture condition is not met.

Comment: Does it mean the proof has to do case analysis: if y is free in M we follow this path; otherwise, rename y to something else and proceed in similar venue. Is there a proof without branching?

Comment: @TegiriNenashi: The most convenient way to proceed would be, because you're free to $\alpha$-convert at any time, to _start by_ saying: "Choosen an $\alpha$-renaming of $\lambda xy.x$ such the each variable becomes something that is neither free in $M$ nor in $N$; in the following, assume that the letters $x$ and $y$ stand for whichever such "safe" variable names we choose."

Comment: ...(continued) Often the lambda calculus is defined such the _real_ name of variables _in the calculus_ is always something ugly such as $X''''''''$, and the meaning of the "$x$"s that appear on the page in actual proofs is always a meta-variable that ranges over the ugly "real" variable names. (Another somewhat popular convention is that calculus-level variable names are in typewriter-style like `x`, and things in mathematics fonts like $x$ are always metavariables that range over variable names).